# Why StreamedResponse() from Symfony 6 is sent at once?

Tags: php, symfony

As in the title described i want to send some data in runtime from Symfony 6 with StreamedResponse() class.

The docs example looks like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

$response = new StreamedResponse();
$response->setCallback(function () {
    var_dump('Hello World');
    //ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(2);
    var_dump('Hello World');
    //ob_flush();
    flush();
});
$response->send();
```

The above example gives the complete output at the end of the script. Some other ideas were to put ob_flush() before flush() but this doesnt change anything.
in my php.ini was `output_buffering = 4096`
Is there another place to change something to send messages at runtime?

### Edit (1)

Here is the additional try from a comment with the same result:

```
    @ob_end_clean();     
    ini_set('output_buffering', 0);          

    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->headers->set('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type: ', 'text/event-stream');
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, must-revalidate');
    $response->setCallback(function () {
        echo 'Hello World';
        //ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(3);
        var_dump('Hello World');
        //ob_flush();
        flush();
    });
    $response->send();

return $response;
```

The response headers are:

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-cache, private
Content-Type:: text/event-stream
Date: Wed, 31 May 2023 13:54:51 GMT
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=h26uhmnc7nq6sibu6ed566k9oe; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=lax
X-Accel-Buffering: no
X-Powered-By:PHP/8.1.6
```

Comment: And how you are reading this output? Maybe your tool only shows output when request has finished?

Comment: E.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740646/jquery-read-ajax-stream-incrementally

Comment: to answer both of you: i try ro fetch this with postman and with ajax from symfony and standalone php. I get only the complete output (the example of your link gives me `Begin... (counting to 10)12345678910End...` in 1 Response

Comment: After `response->send()` there is no need to return the response again, the controller method can return `void`.

Comment: The method works, `ob_end_clean` is important. I'm using mime-type `text/plain` and the output streams into the browser window, with `text/event-stream` however the browser downloads an attachment file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```php
@ob_end_clean();
ini_set('output_buffering', 0);
$response->headers->set('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');
```

**Explain**

`output_buffering` in `php.ini` will buffer streaming output 100%. To disable it dynamically for individual endpoints, it is not enough to call `ini_set`, you also need to reset the accumulated buffer via `@ob_end_clean` (@ - to avoid problems on those environments where the buffer is disabled)

Also often buffering occurs in nginx or something like that. The most convenient way to reset it is through the `X-Accel-Buffering` header.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/76084561/21333278, although it's about Yii, but the proposed solution is universal

Comment: Its the same behavior. The whole response come at once when the script is finishing

Comment: I checked this code on my Symfony 6, everything works with it (although without it it also sends whole at once). Have you tried the code from the suggested link with setting headers via native php functions like:
```php
    @ob_end_clean();
    ini_set('output_buffering', 0);
    
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("X-Accel-Buffering: no");
```
Also what do the response headers contain?

Comment: i added it in the question above. Can you show me your controller function?

Comment: There is a typo in your example. Try to remove ":" (colon) sign from 'Content-Type: ' to 'Content-Type'. The rest of the code is working, my controller:
```
    #[Route('test-stream', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function testStream()
    {
# your code
}```

Comment: ok, thats exactly what i have done. Then i have no idea whats wrong.

Comment: @DanielRichter Did you find a solution for that ? I have the same problem (Symfony 6.3)

Comment: Not at the Moment, but anywhere i have read that it doesnt work with the symfony dev Server, but in my case it Changed nothing beteuern public and dev.